# How can I downgrade from Lollipop to KitKat

Tags: updates, 5.0-lollipop

Not at all happy with Lollipop on my Z3 compact. My battery lasts half a day and I'm not keen on new format

How can I downgrade and get back to Kit-kat?

Comment: See **Search and Research** here [ask]. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 5):

There is a list of ROMs available for Z3 at XDA.
Please visit the link and flash your device with an appropriate ROM and you are done. :)

[Sony Xperia Z3 ROMs [XDA]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/z3#romList)

Comment: +1 Could you [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/106132/edit) and cite the list as well. In case XDA link goes down in future,  at least the reader will have something to hold on to.